# Leapday offset - cleaner solution anyone?

Tags: java, leap-year

I needed to define start/end dates for a person's given age.  This seemed simple:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(dateOfBirth);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, years);
Date start = cal.getTime();

cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);    
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
Date end = cal.getTime();
```

Ah, but then there are those born on Leap Day Feb 29th.  If the age is not a multiple of 4 then Calendar will round down to the 28th.  In this case, my code above will give a date range ending on Feb 27th, and there'll be a gap.

So, I can easily solve this by checking for this condition, and I can wrap the fix up in some method to avoid duplicating it everywhere.  But I'm wondering, is there a better solution I'm not aware of?  Something that automatically accounts for this special case for a "day before/after" problem?

Here's my solution:

```
public static Date getAgeStartEnd(Date d, int age, boolean end) {
    if (d == null) return null;

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(d);
    int baseDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, age + (end ? 1 : 0));
    int newDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    boolean roundedDown = baseDay != newDay;

    if (end && !roundedDown) 
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    else if (!end && roundedDown)
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    d = cal.getTime();
    return d;      
}

Date start = getAgeStartEnd(dateOfBirth, years, false);
Date end   = getAgeStartEnd(dateOfBirth, years, true);
```

Comment: It's not clear what "gap" you mean - or why you're using `Date`. If you can possibly use the java.time package, you can use `LocalDate` which is a *much* better API. You'll still need to think about the same problems, but the solution will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet.  I'm using Date because it's an old, huge application. But that's why I'm really using Calendar.  The "gap" is that `leapDay + age` will automatically round down to the 28th so my "day before" offset will further bump it down to the 27th, and the 28th will be neglected.  However, the start of the next range will likewise be rounded down to include the 28th, but this isn't any better because the person would be the wrong age on that day.

Comment: or Joda if you can't use 1.8

Comment: Why don't you just have *one* method to get the user's birthday after N years... and to get the range, just call it once with N, and once with N+1, subtracting a day from the N+1 result if you really have to. (Ideally, just make the end exclusive though...)

Comment: I believe that's pretty much what I've shown in my solution, except that I've incorporated the -1d end-exclusion to keep the calling code clean. I agree life would have been simpler if the consumers of this range were inclusive-exclusive, but like I said it's a very large, very old application.